# List of dates, need count of each date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of rows with date and want a count of how many times each date appears in the column. I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! More details are needed. Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: Research using a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the dates but just want a count then you can use countif.

=countif(daterange,date)